# Java Netty остановка сервера

Tags: сервер, netty

Как в Netty остановить сервер?

Answer (score 1):

Что бы остановить сервер.

```
    public class Server {
    private Channel channel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        EventLoopGroup producer = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup consumer = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap().group(producer, consumer)
               .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
               .childHandler(new Initializer(new NetHandlerPlayServer(this), State.server));
            channel = bootstrap.bind(Config.port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            producer.shutdownGracefully();
            consumer.shutdownGracefully();
            channel.disconnect();//Останавливаем сервер.
        }
    }

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
}
```